# Erro do APK no android studio

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Galera, quando eu tento emular a aplicação me aparece esse erro, alguém pode me ajudar a resolver?

Quando eu clico em ok ele não faz nada, criar outra imagem seria tentar emular dnv? Se sim eu já tentei, com varias plataformas, mas nada da certo...

Comment: Boa Noite. Cara, particularmente eu não uso o Emulador do Android Studio. Não passei por esse erro, mas, aconselho você usa o Genymotion. Ele é bacana. Abraços!

Comment: Se você responde 'OK' ele instala e funciona?

Eu tentaria criar outra imagem de emulador. Quando migrei do Eclipse pro Android Studio, 2/3 das imagens 'velhas' de emulador que eu tinha configurado, tiveram comportamento estranho.(Aliás, o simulador do Android continua sendo ruim.)

Comment: @ViniciusLuciene decidi pelo android studio porque em pesquisas percebi que ele é oque mais tem ferramentas disponiveis para facilitar pra quem é iniciante, eu nunca ouvi falar dessa genymotion. vou dar uma pesquisada aqui.
Obrigado.